# Solve $A B A^T= C$ subject to $Ax=y$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble solving the following problem.

Find $A$ such that $ABA^T=C$ and $Ax=y$.

Here, $B$ and $C$ are known positive definite matrices, and $x$ and $y$ are known vectors. I'm happy to do any necessary leg work if someone can point me to a good resource, but I am having trouble turning anything up on my own.

Comment: Could you give us a bit more context here?  How did you come across this problem?  Are there any tools/techniques that you would expect to work here?

Comment: Also, do we know anything about the size of these matrices?  Are $x$ and $y$ the same sized vector?

Comment: It seems a quadratic programming problem with linear constraints.

Comment: Yes, all matrices are square (say $n by n$) and all vectors are of dimension $n$. This problem is really related to multivariate normal distributions. Without excessive detail, $B$ is the covariance of a random variable with mean $x$, and likewise the relationship between $C$ and $y$. I thought solution methods for Sylvester equations might be useful, but the quadratic terms in the first equation exclude this. I also thought that eigendecomposing $B=PDP^-1$ could help in finding some related equation which is directly soluble, but as $A^T=/=A^-1$ in general, I could not get traction.

Comment: are $B$ and $C$ symmetric?

Comment: Candyman, I am looking for an analytical approach. This is a sub-problem of a larger project I am working on, and a numerical approach is not sufficient for my purposes.

Comment: Will, yes $B$ and $C$ are symmetric. If I am not mistaken, positive definite implies symmetric, but please correct me if I am wrong so I can edit my original post.

Comment: @MichaelNew lots of users on this site live in a world where symmetric is not assumed. I have no idea why. Meanwhile, you get existence of new matrices such that $B = M M^T$ and $C = N N^T.$ Furthermore, if useful, given orthogonal matrix $O,$ you can replace $M$ by $MO,$ or replace $N$ by $NO.$ Oh, for a person to get a little red flag indicating a message, start your comment with an @ sign and their username

Comment: Unless you have additional constraints on $B,C,x,y$ I don't think this is solvable. For instance, consider $B=1$, $C=1$, $x=1$, $y=2$.

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for the tips. I believe you just answered my question as I can rewrite my first equation as $AMM^TA^T=NN^T$, from which it follows $AM=N$ and $A=Ninv(M)$. Also, I believe $M$ and $N$ should be easily computed from eigendecompositions of $A$ and $B$. If I am missing something then let me know, and thank you for your help!

Comment: @tch You may be correct. I may have to reframe my problem or look for a least-squares solution, but I think I have what I need for now.

Comment: @MichaelNew note that it is not necessary to find eigenvalues if you are satisfied to find some $W$ such that $W^T B W = D$ is diagonal. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Answer (score 0):

Since you write $A^T$, I suppose your matrices are real.

The equation $ABA^T=C$ means that $C^{-1/2}AB^{1/2}$ is real orthogonal. Hence the general solution is given by $A=C^{1/2}QB^{-1/2}$, where $Q$ is an arbitrary real orthogonal matrix.

If you want $Ax=y$, you need to solve $Q(B^{-1/2}x)=C^{-1/2}y$ for a real orthogonal $Q$. Clearly this is solvable if and only if $\|B^{-1/2}x\|_2=\|C^{-1/2}y\|_2$. When it is indeed solvable, you may pick any real orthogonal matrix that maps $B^{-1/2}x$ to $C^{-1/2}y$. For instance, when $B^{-1/2}x=C^{-1/2}y$, simply pick $Q=I$; otherwise, you may pick the Householder reflection matrix $Q=I-2ww^T$ where
$$
w=\frac{B^{-1/2}x-C^{-1/2}y}{\|B^{-1/2}x-C^{-1/2}y\|}.
$$